# Animate Each ng-repeat itineration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-animate

Hello I've been stuck on this all morning, I want to make an animation for each block that I generate with ng-repeat, I cant make it works

here is the html:

```
<div class="blocks-container" ng-init="loadProjects()" ng-controller="buildMonitorController">
<div class="row">
    <div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block"
             ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate' : true"
             ng-animate="{enter: 'animate-enter', leave: 'animate-leave'}"
             ng-class="{'running': project.running ,'block-green': build._status ==='SUCCESS','block-red': build._status==='FAILURE'}"
             id="{{build._id}}">
            <div class="title-container"><p>{{build._buildTypeId}}</p></div>
            <div class="update-container col-xs-12">
            <time>{{ build.lastBuildDetails.startDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:s'}}</time>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Start error state dialog -->
<div ng-include src="'views/main/error-dialog.html'"></div>
```

**Edit I,ve changed the ng-animate to this:**

```
  ng-animate="{enter: 'block-enter'}" style="transition-delay:500ms"
```

and created the following rules in the css file:

```
.block-enter {
    opacity:0;
    -webkit-transition-property: all;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
}
.block-enter.block-enter-active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

But still not working :(

Comment: Can you share it in plunker

Comment: You can check this [link](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2460)

Comment: The version is Angular-1.3.15

Sorry I cant share in plunker because im getting the data from a localhost server and cant do it in plunker(or i dont know how to do it)  :(

Comment: Provide delay : ng-animate="{enter: 'block-enter', delay: 500}" or use style="transition-delay: {{$index * 500}}ms"

Comment: I've changed it but still not working, here is a an example of how this working right now http://recordit.co/nZRpaebWzm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm answering my question for anyone with the same problem can fix it.
In AngularJS 1.3.15 ng-animate is deprecated, If you want to use animation simply create an animation in css and add it to the class:

Here is my code use it as example:
I use the class animate for the animation

HTML:

```
<div class="blocks-container" ng-init="loadProjects()" ng-controller="buildMonitorController">
<div class="row">
   <!-- <div> -->
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
             ng-repeat="build in builds.builds.build track by build._id | orderBy:'lastBuildDetails.startDate' : true"
             ng-class="{'running': project.running ,'block-green': build._status ==='SUCCESS','block-red': build._status==='FAILURE'}"
             id="{{build._id}}">
            <div class="title-container"><p>{{build._buildTypeId}}</p></div>
            <div class="update-container col-xs-12">
            <time>{{ build.lastBuildDetails.startDate | date : 'dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:s'}}</time>
            </div>
        </div>
    <!--</div>-->
</div>
<!-- Start error state dialog -->
<div ng-include src="'views/main/error-dialog.html'"></div>
```

CSS:

```
//Animation V3/////////////////////////////////
.animate.ng-move,
.animate.ng-enter,
.animate.ng-leave {
    -webkit-transition:all linear 0.5s;
    transition:all linear 0.5s;
}

.animate.ng-leave.ng-leave-active,
.animate.ng-move,
.animate.ng-enter {
    opacity:0;
    //max-height:0;
}

.animate.ng-leave,
.animate.ng-move.ng-move-active,
.animate.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
    opacity:1;
    //max-height:40px;
}

/**
 * Stagger Leave (hide) animation
 */
.animate.ng-leave-stagger {
    /* this will have a 100ms delay between each successive leave animation */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;

    /* in case the stagger doesn't work then these two values
     must be set to 0 to avoid an accidental CSS inheritance */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}

/**
 * Stagger ENTER ANIMATION
 */
.animate.ng-enter-stagger {
    /* this will have a 100ms delay between each successive enter animation */
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;

    /* in case the stagger doesn't work then these two values
     must be set to 0 to avoid an accidental CSS inheritance */
    -webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
    transition-duration: 0s;
}
```

AngularJS Module:

```
var app = angular.module('saTeamcityBuildMonitorAngularWebApp', ['buildMonitor-controller', 'cb.x2js','countdown-controller','ngAnimate']);
```